# Are there downsides to having a large number of Drupal Regions?

Tags: drupal

I have a Drupal 6 site where there are several different layouts, and as much as I've tried to narrow down the regions required to create the variety, I have a total of 15 regions. Will this cause any problems? Especially speed problems?

(I am not using Panels or similar with this site and do not plan on doing so)

Thanks for any input you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't really cause any problems.  It may be a little hairy and difficult to preview things on the Blocks admin page.

For example, the [Newsflash](http://drupal.org/project/newsflash) theme has 13 regions and I have never had any issues with it

Comment: I didn't really think it'd cause any problems, but I wasn't sure. Thanks!